# Github actions 'pull_request_review' on a specific target branch

Tags: github-actions

We are trying to setup a github action which only triggers on `pull_request_review` for pull requests targeted to a specific base branch pattern `release/*`

This is so we have a GH action be able to check if the review is from a specific release gatekeeper group.

Doing something like so, does not seem to work only for PR's targeted to `release/*` branches. It seems to trigger on PR reviews target to all base branches

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    branches:
      - release/*
```

Seems to us that we cannot chain the base branch like so

Comment: Side note – you could maybe solve that with [code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) and setting branch protections rules for `release/*` to ["Require review from Code Owners"](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches#require-pull-request-reviews-before-merging).

Answer (score 1):

You can perform filtering at job level.

Example:

```yaml
name: Filtering PR Reviews

on:
  pull_request_review:
    branches:
      - 'releases/**'

jobs:
  Releases:
    name: Releases
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ startsWith( github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'releases/' )}}
    steps:
      - name: trigger
        run: echo "we are in releases/**"
    
  ReleasesNext:
    name: ReleasesNext
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ startsWith( github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'releases/next' )}}
    steps:
      - name: trigger
        run: echo "we are in releases/next"
```

Comment: Yes it seems that this is the way to go. What I dont like about this is that the action will still trigger but 'skip' the job.

Comment: Exactly.
You could create a secondary workflow triggering the appropriate actions.
This dummy job would still trigger though.
You might get better organization with your pipelines that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by setting condition as in:

```
on:
pull_request_review:
    branches:
        - release/**

jobs:
  release-job:
    if: startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'release/')
```

This basically checks base reference for text (not case sensitive).

If the condition is false the wf will be still displayed among other ones, but will be shown as skipped (0s execution time).

Note that you would need to set this if condition for every job in a workflow.

I don't think you need branch filter anymore.

Comment: Yes it seems that this is the way to go. What I dont like about this is that the action will still trigger but 'skip' the job. A